# 'As' for contiguous time

Tags: meaning, grammar

> "I could have told you that would happen before you even started," said Jane as she sucked on the straw of her cola.

In this sentence, Jane is obviously not performing a ventriloquist type act. The actions are not simultaneous but consecutive, but would *as* work to express this?

I could try,

> "I could have told you that would happen before you even started," said Jane, then she sucked on the straw of her cola.

But here I have created a comma splice, and a semicolon just doesn’t seem to work. It separates the actions too much in time.

Or I could try,

> "I could have told you that would happen before you even started," said Jane before she sucked on the straw of her cola.

Again the same problem, I have separated the sense of the actions too much in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you word it right the sucking on the straw doesn't even need to happen. I'd reword your question. "As" is perfectly valid under English rules. I've seen it used many times and it is perfectly acceptable. There is no need to overcomplicate it. Obviously it is not a "ventriloquy act". If you really want to emphasize that she has made her point, I would just italicize "told" and move on. I'd say the way she says her dialogue will emphasize what you want more than the act of sucking on her straw. It looks fine and is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

Given the information that Jane was not previously sucking on her straw, but started doing so rather demonstratively in order to show that she had now delivered her piece, the most natural phrasing would to me be something like:

> “I could have told you that would happen before you even started”, Jane said and sucked/started sucking on the straw of her cola as if to drive home the point.

Answer (score 2):

How do you like:

> While sucking on the straw of her cola, Jane stopped and said, "I could have told you that would happen before it even started."

or

> As Jane sucked on the straw of her cola, she stopped to say, "I could have told you that would happen before it even started."

or

> "I could have told you that would happen before you even started," said Jane, pausing from sucking on the straw of her cola.

or

> "I could have *told* you that would happen before you even started," said Jane, sucking on her straw. She'd made her point.

or

> "I could have *told* you that would happen before you even started," said Jane, proceeding to suck on her straw. She'd made her point.

Comment: I like your answers, but the context of the dialogue is that it is a retort with an action to express this. The dialogue and action are unified in meaning, but not in time.

Comment: When in time is it happening? It sounded to me like she was sipping on the straw, saying something, and then continuing to sip?

Comment: No, I wanted to express that she emphasised her comment by sucking on the straw, as though she'd made her point. It was an emphatic gesture. The comment and action express the same thing.

Comment: How about either of these last two. I think the italicization of "told" helps with the emphasis as well.

Comment: @RoDaSm, you should include this information in the question itself. There is no way of knowing that you meant this just by reading the question as it is now—I too assumed that sucking on the straw was something Jane paused from doing while making her statement.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, but the question is really about using 'as' for contiguous time, and the question does work for this. The context given was for meer2cat, who is offering some very good suggestions for alternative wording, which I appreciate, but the question has to be a valid question of English usage.

Comment: There is a rule for writing which is show don't say, and Jane sucking on her straw shows her disdain.

Comment: I think if you word it right the sucking on the straw doesn't even need to happen. I'd reword your question. "As" is perfectly valid under English rules.

Comment: Added a new answer to fit the question you are actually asking.

Answer (score -3):

"You should have asked me before you started - I knew that would happen" said Jane condescendingly.

---

Jane is making a statement.

Sucking on straw - shows her disinterest

"I could have told you" - condescending

---

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.